# Create new variable or reassign the old one - php

Tags: php, performance, variables

What is less expensive in terms of performance and why ? Though for the first case it creates new variable, but in second case should not it first unset the `var1` to reassign it ?

```
1) 
$var1 = $someBigArray;
$var2 = $this->someFunction($var1);

// use $var2

2) 
$var1 = $someBigArray;
$var1 = $this->someFunction($var1);

// user $var1
```

**UPDATE**

I cant really do this, I just excluded the rest of my code, asking the core part and making it look simpler
`$var1 = $this->someFunction($someBigArray);`

Comment: Why dont you try this `$var1 = $this->someFunction($someBigArray);`

Comment: Is 1) causing performance problems?

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 I updated the qsn, tks

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, now no, but I just want to consider the case if `$someBigArray` becomes huge. tks

Answer (score 0):

There you have two things, One is processing other is memory.

About Processing:

In PHP you really don't know what is the type of the variable. if the variable type of $someBigArray and $this->someFunction($var1) are not the same, it will be lot more expensive then assigning a new variable $var2. if they are same type($someBigArray and $this->someFunction($var1)), then it is less expensive.(less processing)

About memory:
using the same variable will may use less memory. small optimization for the RAM.

Memory is cheap, You should be more careful about the processing power your using. In these cases, try to do a benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's garbage collection is a bit weird and when overriding a variable it isn't (always?) flushed from memory. So memory wise, assign a new variable and use `unset()` on the old one. You don't really want 30Mb of array wasting away in your memory, especially if this is a script that runs for any length of time or if you ever have multiple of it running at once.

I don't know about processing performance. As Nafis said, try a benchmark. (Simplest and dumbest way, make a script that runs it 1000 times and see which is faster)

Comment: Can you support your answer with verifiable data?

Comment: Only via experimentation. Try testing with memory_get_usage();